# How to give texture to object in dae file as using 3D Viewer component in SAP UI5?

Tags: javascript, three.js, sapui5, textures, collada

I am opening dae file in SAP UI5 as using 3D Viewer component and thridparty library(three.js). I am giving texture to these boxes at runtime stage. But I cannot see the changes of texture in box. When I move object by the mouse I can see the changes. How can I see the changes texture at runtime stage without moving the mouse?

I'm following this link: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.ui.vk.tutorial.VIT/sample/sap.ui.vk.tutorial.VIT.08

```
     <mvc:View controllerName="colladaLoader.controller.App" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:c="sap.ui.core" xmlns:vk="sap.ui.vk"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true">
<Shell>
    <App id="colladaLoader">
        <Page title="{i18n>pageTitle}">
            <vk:Viewer id="viewer" selectionChanged="selectionChanged" sceneLoadingSucceeded="sceneLoadingSucceeded">
                <vk:contentResources>
                    <vk:ContentResource id="viewerResource" source="models/boxes.dae" sourceType="dae"
                        name="Collada Model"/>
                </vk:contentResources>
            </vk:Viewer>
        </Page>
    </App>
</Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

//Controller;

//library  : "sap/ui/vk/threejs/thirdparty/three"

```
    onInit: function () {
        var that = this
        var colladaLoader = function (parentNode, contentResource) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var url = "https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js";
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "script",
                    cache: true
                }).done(function () {
                    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
                    loader.load(contentResource.getSource(),
                        function (collada) { // onload

                            parentNode.add(collada.scene);
                            resolve({
                                node: parentNode,
                                contentResource: contentResource
                            });

                            dae = collada.scene;
                            dae.traverse(function (child) {
                                objects.push(child);
                            });
                            that.onChangeTextture();
                        },
                        null,// onprogress
                        reject // onfail


                    );

                }).fail(function () {
                    MessageToast.show("Cannot load Collada loader from " + url);
                    reject();
                });

            });

        };


        ContentConnector.addContentManagerResolver({
            pattern: "dae",
            dimension: 3,
            contentManagerClassName: "sap.ui.vk.threejs.ContentManager",
            settings: {
                loader: colladaLoader
            }
        });

    },
```

//ChangeTexture code blog

```
    onChangeTextture : function(){
        var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        var textureGreen = textureLoader.load('./materials/Green.jpg');
        var textureRed = textureLoader.load('./materials/red.jpg');

        objects[2].material.map = null;
        objects[2].material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

        setInterval(function(){ 
            var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

            if(number % 2 === 0) {
                objects[2].material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                        map: textureGreen
                    });
                objects[2].material.needsUpdate = true;
                objects[2].material.map.needsUpdate = true;
            }
            else {
                objects[2].material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map: textureRed
                });
                objects[2].material.needsUpdate = true;
                objects[2].material.map.needsUpdate = true;
            }}, 3000);
    }![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTKPC.gif)
```

Comment: Can you please verify if the geometry of your Collada mesh actually has texture (uv) coordinates?

Comment: @Mugen87Hi, thank you for answer. Texture coordinates are true, I can see texture on box. My problem; I can see texture when I moved canvas by the mouse.I want to see the changes texture at runtime stage without moving the mouse.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with your 3D viewer but I guess you have to trigger a redraw in some way. Viewers often have no animation loop so they render their scene only on certain events like interaction.

Comment: @Mugen87 Thank you for your interest. I'm gonna keep researching and try.